# Testing the strength of a B filed from loop of wire and limitations of a function generator

Tags: power, electromagnetism, inductance, function-generator

I built a coil that receives magnetic fields (Rx) from a sending coil (Tx) a few centimeters away. (wireless power transfer) I send waves to the Tx at the Rx's resonant frequency since its a loop with a capacitor in parallel. (RLC circuit) Wave sent to the Tx is in the 200kHz range so no impedance matching 
 
Im testing if the addition of a iron like material increases the voltage. Almost like a transformer with an air gap.
It turns out it did, not much surprise but Im wondering by how much.

Then I thought. The addition of the material brought down the resonate frequency I was sending the B field at. My test coil (No iron) had a resonant frequency at 212kHz and my coil with the iron had a resonant frequency of 191kHz. Think this checks out because f resonant has a 1/sqrt(L) relationship, so the iron raised L and brought down f. 
My issue. The two different frequencies will have two different impedances on my sending coil. Since one test had a frequency of 212kHz and one 191kHz, the 191kHz Tx sends slightly more power because the 191kHz experiences less impedance. Is this correct? Did some rough math (I know the L value for my Tx coil) and a 10Vpp wave experienced like 2.6 ohm for 212kHz and 2.4 ohm for 191kHz. This is like around 9 amps for 212kHz and 8 amps 191kHz. The function generators spec sheet said that it has a .2 max amp output. So did both my tests receive this max current of .2 amps? 
If there was no current output limit, the impedance of my Tx would effect the B field?

Also may be silly question but if your sending a 10Vpp wave down a wire with little resistance, how does the function generator limit the current to .2 amps. Thank you

Comment: Chris, measure the AC signal going into that coil with a really good meter (has to be rated for >220kHz RMS measurement capability) or a 'scope to see what the signal actually is. The function generator is probably clipping at a much lower voltage, resulting in a square wave.

Comment: It's funny I'm at work thinking of all this. So after I posted, I thought I could just measure the current. Hopefully my meter at home can do the trick. I'm actually sending a square wave because that increased the power transfer for a reason I'm not entirely sure (Square wave has a higher rms maybe?) I guess really i'm wondering if the slight difference in frequency can be ignored. I'm really trying to send as consistent a magnetic field as I can.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8aZoM9p43k  ,little video I made a while back of my setup. Its different in some ways but gives an idea